# Difference between clean workspace and clean all projects in RAD

Tags: eclipse, build, workspace

Is there any difference between clean workspace and clean all projects in RAD? I assume both these tasks will delete all compiled sources etc from our output directories (eg. target\classes) for all the projects.

I am able to do "clean all projects" for my worspace but when I do "clean workspace" (or build workspace) it gives error in dialog box "The file does not exist for the external tool named Clean Workspace." Why does it happen?

Update:Clean Workspace will delete all target folders used by Maven. So Clean Workspace is used only with Maven?